# Datagrid Update Checkbox IsChecked on DataGrid.Refresh()

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid who's ItemsSource is a strongly typed IEnumerable object

In this datagrid, I have a checkbox column, a price column, a part name column, and a 'total selling for' column.

On checking the checkbox I need to update the total selling for column with the value in the price column.

This part I have working, however, how can I get the checkbox to remain checked when this happens?

```
Private Sub UpdateSellFor(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim _CB As CheckBox = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)
    Dim _ID As Integer = _CB.Tag
    Dim _PP = DirectCast(DG_PartsToSelect.CurrentItem, PartTyping).PartPrice
    If _CB.IsChecked Then
        DG_PartsToSelect.CurrentItem.PartSellingFor = DirectCast(DG_PartsToSelect.CurrentItem, PartTyping).PartPrice
        DG_PartsToSelect.Items.Refresh()
    Else

    End If
    '_CB.IsChecked = True
End Sub
```

uncommenting _CB.IsChecked = True does nothing

Here's the XAML for this datagrid:

```
                <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3" Name="DG_PartsToSelect" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Part ID" Binding="{Binding PartID}" />
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Part Name">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PartName}" Cursor="Hand" MouseDown="PartDetails" Tag="{Binding PartID}" ToolTip="Click to See the Part Details" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Selling For" Binding="{Binding PartPrice, StringFormat='{}{0:C}'}" />
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Part Options">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Cursor="Hand" Height="22" Name="options" Tag="{Binding PartID}" MouseDown="PartOptions" Source="/v2Desktop;component/Images/Application.png" ToolTip="Select Part Options" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Sell This Part">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox Name="SelectedPart" Tag="{Binding PartID}" ToolTip="Select This Part" Click="UpdateSellFor" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total Selling For" Binding="{Binding PartSellingFor, StringFormat='{}{0:C}'}" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Just a guess but do you by accident created the TextBox inside a TemplateColum in the CellTemplate, otherwise provide us some xaml please. Come to think of it; Please do provide the xaml.

Comment: The checkbox is a template, yes, but not the Total Selling For

Comment: What happens most of the time is that a checkbox in a CellTemplate without for example the CellEditingTemplate resets upon check to false, because looking at your approach makes me assume you do not have a binding on the checkbox in your xaml.

Comment: not officially no.  but the .Tag is bound

Comment: I would suggest you add an IsCalculated DependencyProperty to the Binded class and Bind the CheckBox to that. Inside the PropertyChangedCallbackHandler you can update the prices for that row using the `DependencyObject d` as your item. Let me know if you would like an example.

Comment: I'm going to create an example on how to more properly do a datagrid, don't be offended, I mean it in the nicest way.

Comment: i will not be offended :)  yes please, thank you ;)  I'm pretty noob with WPF

Comment: I've created an example not using dependencyproperties, but just the familiar properties, so it will not be overcomplicated.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how it is more the WPF way, hopefully this gets you in the right direction.
It has been a long time since I touched Visual Basic so please mind some missed conventions by me.

The Xaml:

```
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3" x:Name="DG_PartsToSelect" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=ID}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Selling For">
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SellingPrice, StringFormat='{}{0:C}', Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SellingPrice, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Part Options">
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <Border Background="#88BBFF" Cursor="Hand" Height="22" ToolTip="Select Part Options" MouseUp="PartOptions_MouseUp"/><!--just for testing with no image-->
              <!--<Image Cursor="Hand" Height="22" Source="" ToolTip="Select Part Options" MouseDown="PartOptions_MouseDown"/>-->
            </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Sell This Part">
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <CheckBox Name="SelectedPart" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsCalculated, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ToolTip="Select This Part"  />
            </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Total Selling For" Binding="{Binding Path=TotalSellingFor, StringFormat='{}{0:C}'}" />
      </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Code Behind (Window Class and Part Class):

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Class MainWindow

  Dim Parts As ObservableCollection(Of Part)

  Private Sub PartOptions_MouseUp(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
    If DG_PartsToSelect.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
      Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim selectedPart = DirectCast(DG_PartsToSelect.SelectedItem, Part)
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The name = {0}", selectedPart.Name), String.Format("The id = {0}", selectedPart.ID), MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information)
  End Sub

  Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Parts = New ObservableCollection(Of Part)
    Parts.Add(New Part(1, "test", 100D))
    Parts.Add(New Part(2, "Name here", 99.99D))
    Parts.Add(New Part(3, "What", 23.19D))
    DG_PartsToSelect.DataContext = Parts
  End Sub
End Class

Public Class Part : Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

  Private IDField As Integer
  Public Property ID() As Integer
    Get
      Return IDField
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
      IDField = value
      OnPropertyChanged("ID")
    End Set
  End Property

  Private NameField As String
  Public Property Name() As String
    Get
      Return NameField
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
      NameField = value
      OnPropertyChanged("Name")
    End Set
  End Property

  Private SellingPriceField As Decimal
  Public Property SellingPrice() As Decimal
    Get
      Return SellingPriceField
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
      SellingPriceField = value
      OnPropertyChanged("SellingPrice")
      IsCalculatedField = False
      OnPropertyChanged("IsCalculated")
    End Set
  End Property

  Private IsCalculatedField As Boolean
  Public Property IsCalculated() As Boolean
    Get
      Return IsCalculatedField
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
      If (IsCalculatedField And Not value) Then
        Exit Property
      End If
      IsCalculatedField = value
      UpdateTotalPrice()
    End Set
  End Property

  Private TotalSellingForField As Decimal
  Public Property TotalSellingFor() As Decimal
    Get
      Return TotalSellingForField
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
      TotalSellingForField = value
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler _
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

  Public Sub New(id As Integer, name As String, sellingPrice As Decimal)
    IDField = id
    NameField = name
    SellingPriceField = sellingPrice
  End Sub

  Sub UpdateTotalPrice()
    ''This will multiply the price of the SellingPriceValue times 2 and put it in the TotalSellingForField
    TotalSellingForField = SellingPriceField * 2
    OnPropertyChanged("TotalSellingFor")
  End Sub

  Sub OnPropertyChanged(propertyName As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I am getting an error on this line already:
        Public Event PropertyChanged As ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

on INotifyPropertyChanged with no suggestions

Comment: states INotifyPropertyChanged is not defined

Comment: nevermind, I was missing that : Implements INotifyPropertyChanged...  DOH...  see NOOB

Comment: So you got me in the right direction.  the solution was actually much simpler than that.  I did need to bind the IsChecked on the checkbox itself, I created a new property in my PartsTyping class as boolean = false, and then in the UpdateSellFor, I simply change the value of that field to True (and back to false if clicked again)

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to award multiple solutions as the answer?

Comment: @o7thWebDesign You cannot accept multiple solutions, accepting one and voting up the other one is the most you can do. I would in addition recommend not to put events in templates. It's your call. Just accept which answer suited the question more, not which answer is better.:)

Comment: Having a similar issue with a textbox in the same grid.  I am attempting the same method I am using (simply changing the property), however, on refresh it is not keeping the change

Comment: @o7thWebDesign Add UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged to the Binding on the TextBox, this way the setter of the property gets triggered on every 'live' change.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure what is happening is this Event is fired before the update (set).  So when you refresh you are getting the prior value.   Assign the value of the CheckBox to the Property before you call refresh.

Comment: Which event?  Set what property?   Please see the code I posted.  It contains everything that happens in the 'Click' event of the checkbox

Comment: Exactly and there is more going on then that click event.   Check the Set on _cb - does it get called and what value is passed?

Comment: "check the Set"???  Just not sure what you mean by that.  When I debug the code, the checkbox is the the entire way through...

Comment: You have NO binding for the data on <CheckBox Name="SelectedPart" !   You need to bind IsChecked two way to a boolean property.  Check the Set on the boolean property you bind to.